# Showing that a recurrently defined sequence is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is a text book question.

> Show that the sequence $\{u_n\}$ is convergent where $0<u_1<u_2$ and $u_{n+2}=\frac{2u_{n+1}+u_n}{3}$.

I am aware that it's possible to find the formula of this sequence using the roots of the characteristic equation $x^2=\frac{2x+1}{3}$ and following that apply limit $n\to\infty$. I found that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} u_n=\frac{u_1+3u_2}{4}$.

However, I want to show the existence of this limit analytically. Here's my attempt.

Given that $0<u_1<u_2$, these results follow.

$u_3=\frac{2u_2+u_1}{3}\implies u_1<u_3<u_2$

$ u_4=\frac{2u_3+u_2}{3}\implies u_3<u_4<u_2$

$u_5=\frac{2u_4+u_3}{3}\implies u_3<u_5<u_4$

The idea is that, for a given list of numbers (not all equal) $a_1, a_2,  \cdots , a_n$, the arithmetic mean i.e., $\overline a=\frac{1}{n}\sum a_i$ lies somewhere between $\min(a_i)$ and $\max(a_i)$.

$\therefore 0<u_1<u_3<u_5<\cdots<u_{2n-1}<\cdots<u_2 \\ \text{ and } \\ u_2>u_4>u_6>\cdots>u_{2n}>\cdots>u_1\tag*{} $

Conclusion:

- The odd subsequence of $u$ is monotone increasing and it is bounded above by $u_2$.
- The even subsequence of $u$ is monotone decreasing and it is bounded below by $u_1$.
- By monotone convergence theorem, both these subsequences are convergent.

At this point, I think it's sufficient to show that these two subsequences converge to the same limit. **I am not sure how to do this.**

Initially, I tried to do this proof with the Cauchy criterion for convergence, but I couldn't work it out. I would be interested to see anyone accomplishing it.

Comment: Use that $u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}=(u_n-u_{n+1})/3$

Comment: OK, so say the odd subsequence has limit $L_o$ and the even subsequence has limit $L_e$.  Then from $u_{n+2} = \frac{2 u_{n+1} + u_n}{3}$, if you restrict to even $n$ and take the limit as $n \to \infty$, you get...

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oh, yes, that makes sense! I didn't think about this simple substitution and was trying to figure out sups and infs of these subsequences in my mind and got confused. We get $L_e = \frac{2L_o+L_e}{3}\tag*{}$ I think, we are through. $\blacksquare$

Comment: note that there are constants $A,B$   such that $u_n = A+ B \left( \frac{-1}{3} \right)^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had asked this question on [my Quora space](https://themathhub.quora.com/) as well and got response from [Lai](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/732917/lai) there. [Link to his answer](https://qr.ae/pyewVg). I'm sharing his proof which reveals some ingenious insights to this sequence.

The key insight from his algebraic manipulation is that **absolute difference between successive terms is being reduced to one-third every time as we move along the sequence**! So we can intuitively think that eventually the terms will become arbitrarily close.

> I am going to prove $\{u_n\}$ is convergent by Cauchy Criterion. First of all, we make use of the relation. For convenience, let $\Delta=u_2-u_1>0$.
> $\begin{aligned}& u_{n+2}= \frac{2 u_{n+1}+u_n}{3} \\\Leftrightarrow \quad &3 u_{n+2}=2 u_{n+1}+u_n \\ \Leftrightarrow \quad & 3\left(u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}\right)=(-1)\left(u_{n+1}-u_n\right) \\\Leftrightarrow \quad & u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}=-\frac{1}{3}\left(u_{n+1}-u_n\right)= \cdots &=\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n \Delta\cdots (*) \end{aligned}\tag*{}$
> Use the formula (*) repeatedly, we get
> $\displaystyle u_{n+1}-u_n=\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1}\Delta\tag*{} $
> For any positive integers $p>q$, we have
> $\displaystyle |u_p-u_q|=\left|\sum_{k=q}^{p-1}\left(u_{k+1}-u_k\right)\right|=\left|\sum_{k=q}^{p-1}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{k-1}\Delta \right|<\Delta \sum_{k=q}^{p-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{k-1}=\frac{9 \Delta}{2}\left(3^{-q}-3^{-p}\right)<\frac{9\Delta}{2\cdot 3^q} \rightarrow 0 \textrm{ as }q\rightarrow \infty \tag*{}$
> By Cauchy Criterion for convergence of a sequence, $\{u_n\}$ is convergent.
> With epsilon- delta notation, we can say that for any $\epsilon >0$, take
> $\displaystyle N =\left[\log _3\left(\frac{9 \Delta}{2 \varepsilon}\right)\right]+1\tag*{}$
> such that for any natural number $p>q>N$, then
> $\displaystyle |u_p-u_q|<\epsilon \tag*{}$

Comment: IT is simpler to use basic  linear algebra to get the growth and decay  components of the sequence. After all, this is a linear system. The $-1/3$ term corresponds to an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$ that defines the iterative dependance $\mathbf{x}_{n+1}=A\mathbf{x}_n$. your sequence coverges tp $\frac{3u_1+u_0}{4}$.

Comment: @Mittens you are right but the original post is intended to be a homework question for an analysis course. University students are expected to rely only on the theorems in a typical analysis syllabus (like Cauchy criterion, monotone convergence, etc.) to accomplish the proof.

Comment: Linear algebra, or even matrix algebra is usually studied before analysis (multivariate calculus for example) so this 2x2 metric methods are well known by then. At least in the place I teach.

Comment: @Mittens I guess it depends on the country and the varsity too. In my uni, they teach calc 1, group theory 1 and real analysis 1 in the fresh year. :)

Answer (score 1):

THe sequence defined in the OP can be considered as a linear dynamical system on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as follows:
$$\begin{pmatrix} x_{n+2}\\ x_{n+1}\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} \frac23 & \frac13\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_{n+1}\\ x_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac23 & \frac13\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{n+1}\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_0\end{pmatrix}
$$

The matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} \frac23 & \frac13\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ has eigenvalues  $\lambda_1=-\frac13$, $\lambda_2=1$. It follows that
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} \frac23 & \frac13\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}= 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ -3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -\frac13 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\frac14\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Consequently
\begin{align}
A^n&= 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ -3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \big(-\frac13\big)^n & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\frac14\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\\&\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ -3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\frac14\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=\frac14\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1\\ 3 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Thus, the sequence $\mathbf{x}_n=[x_{n+1},x_n]^\intercal$ converges to
$$\frac14\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1\\ 3 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{3x_1+x_0}{4} \\ \frac{3x_1+x_0}{4} \end{pmatrix}
$$